# how to optimise mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, query-optimization

I get notification from my web hosting company to optimize MySQL queries in my website.They told me that the running MySql queries for more than 15 seconds is not allowed in shared hosting whereas the mysql query for this domain is running on more than 75 seconds.

But i don't know what to do and where to change to optimize MySQL queries. Please help me to solve this problem.

**User@Host: khabarin_suprusr[khabarin_suprusr] @ localhost [] 

Query_time: 76.546533 Lock_time: 1.408959 Rows_sent: 5 Rows_examined: 3038**

```
use khabarin_portal3;
SET timestamp=1347378163;
SELECT *
FROM (`art_conts`)
JOIN `art_cats` ON `art_cats`.`cat_id`=`art_conts`.`cat_id`
JOIN `art_secs` ON `art_secs`.`sec_id`=`art_cats`.`sec_id`
WHERE `art_conts`.`cont_status` = 'public'
ORDER BY `cont_id` desc
LIMIT 5;
```

**User@Host: khabarin_suprusr[khabarin_suprusr] @ localhost []**strong text** Query_time: 54.002604 Lock_time: 1.403354 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 3033**

```
use khabarin_portal3;
SET timestamp=1347376289;
```

**User@Host: khabarin_suprusr[khabarin_suprusr] @ localhost [] 

Query_time: 24.436448 Lock_time: 13.889496 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 0**

```
use khabarin_portal3;
SET timestamp=1347376151;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM (`art_conts`)
JOIN `art_cats` ON `art_cats`.`cat_id`=`art_conts`.`cat_id`
JOIN `art_secs` ON `art_secs`.`sec_id`=`art_cats`.`sec_id`
WHERE `art_conts`.`cat_id` = '59'
AND `art_conts`.`cont_status` = 'public'
ORDER BY `cont_id` desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

A good start is the use of the Keword "EXPLAIN" in front of your SELECT Statements.

Most of the time there is an incorrect or unused index.

If possible avoid "*" in the statements and select only the rows and columns you really need.

Comment: "If possible avoid the "*" in the statement and select only the rows you really need."
this is myth and it's not true. There is nothing wrong with *

Comment: EXPLAIN is good start. After that putting index on key..
And after that move to dedicated/VPS if needed

Comment: Is it possible if i delete some data from my database that reduces its size. And after that this problem will be solved. I also don't know why this problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Try an index on art_conts as follows:

```
cont_id desc,
cont_status,
cat_id,
sec_id
```

Comment: select now() before and after running the query